# ReSTful Facebook canvas Symfony2 application

Tags: facebook, rest, symfony

As you may know, in order to pass user's informations(`signed_request`) 
to your app, Facebook access canvas(ie: iframe) applications by 
sending them a `POST` request. This mechanism is explained [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/canvas/#auth).

In order to keep ReSTful, what would be the right place in Symfony (which service, 
file...) to implement this Ruby on Rails' trick Pierre Olivier Martel 
descibes here: http://blog.coderubik.com/2011/03/restful-facebook-canvas-app-with-ra... 
, eg: **convert every POST requests containing a 'signed_request' 
parameter to a GET one**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inspired from [Stuck's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6312841/3765)(thanks!) and from Symfony Cookbook:

```
# src/Acme/FacebookBundle/RequestListener.php

namespace Acme\FacebookBundle;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernelInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent;

class RequestListener
{
    public function onCoreRequest(GetResponseEvent $event)
    {
        $request = $event->getRequest();
        if ('POST' == $request->getMethod() && null !== $request->get('signed_request'))
        {
            $request->setMethod('GET');
        }
    }
}
```

**Service Definition:**

```
# app/config/config.yml

services:
    acme.facebookbundle.listener.request:
        class: Acme\FacebookBundle\RequestListener
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.listener, event: core.request, method: onCoreRequest }
```

Answer (score 2):

You could implement a RequestListener like it is done in the RESTBundle: https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/RestBundle/blob/master/EventListener/RequestListener.php